# Trying to delete a node from a binary search tree

Tags: c++, null, binary-search-tree

I'm getting a memory error when I try to display my tree after a node was deleted. 
This is my remove (delete) method:

```
void binarySearchTree::remove(int x, node * r)
{
    bool found = false;
    node * previous = NULL;

    if (root == NULL)
    {cout << "Tree is empty. Nothing to remove." << endl; return;}

    while (!found)
    {
        if (x < r->data)
        {
            previous = r;
            r = r->left;
        }
        else if (x > r->data)
        {
            previous = r;
            r = r->right;
        }
        else
            found = true;
    }


    if (r->left == NULL && r->right == NULL)        //case 1: node to be deleted is a leaf (no children)
    {
        delete r;
        return;
    }
    else if(r->left == NULL && r->right != NULL)    //case 2: node only has a right child
        previous->right = r->right;
    else if (r->left != NULL && r->right == NULL)   //case 2: node only has a left child
        previous->left = r->left;
    else
    {                                               //case 3: node has two children
        node * minNode = findMinNode(r->right);     //finds min node in the right sub tree
        r->data = minNode->data;
        delete minNode;
        return;
    }
    delete r;
}
```

My findMinNode method:

```
binarySearchTree::node * & binarySearchTree::findMinNode(node * r)
{
    if (r == NULL)      //if tree is empty
        return r;

    if (r->left == NULL && r->right == NULL)
        return r;
    else if (r->left != NULL)
        return findMinNode(r->left);
    else
        return findMinNode(r->right);
}
```

My display method (using preorder traversal):

```
void binarySearchTree::display(node * r)
{
    if (r == NULL)
        return;

    display(r->left);
    cout << r->data << endl;
    display(r->right);
}
```

I'm using a public `display()` method which then calls this private `display(node * r)` method.

I know the problem is when I use `delete` because when I stepped through the code and got to my `display()` method, when it checked to see if `r== NULL` on the node I just deleted, the address was not `NULL` with an address of `0x000000000` but instead had `0x000000001`. Because of this my program would crash. I've never encountered this problem before. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I should add that I inserted these values in this exact order: 10, 5, 34, 2, 8, 12, 25, 6, 18, 27, 38, 11. I was trying to remove the node with value 12 because it had two children.

Comment: deleting a pointer does not set it to NULL. Is that what you are expecting?

Comment: @NeilKirk I thought it did? So what would be a good alternative to make this NULL while at the same time deallocating the memory?

Comment: `delete r; r = NULL;`

Comment: @NeilKirk I tried that, still crashes at the same place.

Comment: `r` is a local variable, so setting it to NULL won't set the pointer you originally copied it from to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a node you need to NULL out the pointer that points to it, which in your example can be root, previous->left, or previous->right.  If you change previous to be a `node **` and have it point at the previous pointer (initialized to &root) then you can just say `*previous = null` or `*previous = r->right`.

Comment: If you can elaborate more because I'm not understanding your solution. I tried to do what you said to the best of my understanding but it still crashes.

Comment: In the found loop, use `previous = &r->left; r = r->left`.  If a leaf, `delete r; *previous = null;`.  Only right child: `*previous = r->right;`.  And you'll need to do something similar with `minNode` since the pointer to it will be dangling after you delete it.